when using npm only this sign is showing ⠧
when using npm only this sign is showing** ⠧ **and loads forever and always getting errors when cancelling
even though I have the latest node and npm, I tried to uninstall and reinstall node and npm but nothing changed, still same error

Many command line tools use braille to simulate a "throbber" loading indicator: https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/b1db070cb4a497fd91fd61cf197d28b5d47274bb/lib/utils/display.js#L433

"always getting errors when cancelling" - which errors?

npm error code 1
npm error path C:\Users\user\Desktop\electron\node_modules\electron
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm error RequestError: read ECONNRESET

Only create a folder with name electron inside the following directory C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming
